# What is on Wolverine's head in this picture? Looks like a hindu holy symbol

Tags: marvel, wolverine

I saw this photo in a children's book on the Avengers. My son asked what was going on with his head. I have no idea. Any clues?

[image: Wolverine's head]

Comment: Not sure, but the symbol on his chest is the Iron Fist symbol.  Whatever's happening in this scene, it seems likely that the forehead symbol is related to the Iron Fist mythos, too.

Comment: Nice catch. I thought it was just fire, but you're right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like that is the [Eye Of Agamotto](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Eye_of_Agamotto).

On that wiki page there is a section that specifically mentions Wolverine and the Eye:

> Agamotto inexplicably attacked the world, trying various ploys to
>   bring the Eye to the Light Dimension, apparently unable to take it by
>   force. Brother Voodoo challenged Agamotto for the eye, sending a
>   mystically-empowered Wolverine as his champion. When Daniel Deyll, who
>   was held captive in the Light Dimension, witnessed the battle turning
>   against Wolverine, he intervened: Jericho took the Eye and engaged
>   Agamotto personally, repelling the entity at the cost of his own life.
>
> The Eye's housing was destroyed in the process, and the Eye itself
>   faded from existence, presumably for all time.

The story arc is told in [New Avengers Vol 2 5](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/New_Avengers_Vol_2_5).

> As for combating the first Sorcerer Supreme, Voodoo suggests that he
>   combine the collective powers of everyone around him into a vessel and
>   take the fight to Agamotto. Wolverine volunteers to be the vessel,
>   with Voodoo being his guide. Voodoo then begins the ritual, as his
>   astral form enters Wolverine's body. Once the spell is complete,
>   **Wolverine stands ready, with the symbols of both Hellstrom and Iron
>   Fist embedded on his chest**.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Awesome. I think you nailed it. Thanks!